# ReferenceError: "data" is not defined

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

I'm using React Native. This error message is displayed only on web browser mode (Expo).
It's working fine on mobile (iOS) mode

[image]
I'm trying to import data from a file (import films from '../Helpers/filmsData.js')

I'm calling it in my flatlist :

```
<FlatList
          data= { films } 
          keyExtractor={(item) => item.id.toString()}
          renderItem={({item}) => <Text>{item.title}</Text>}
        />
```

Here my data :

```
// Helpers/filmsData.js

export default data = [
   {
      id:181808,
      vote_average:7.2,
      title:"Star Wars VIII - Les derniers Jedi",
      poster_path:"",
      original_title:"Star Wars: The Last Jedi",
      overview:"Nouvel épisode de la saga. Les héros du Réveil de la force rejoignent les figures légendaires de la galaxie dans une aventure épique qui révèle des secrets ancestraux sur la Force et entraîne de choquantes révélations sur le passé…",
      release_date:"2017-12-13"
   },
   {
      id:181809,
      vote_average:8.1,
      title:"La Guerre des étoiles",
      poster_path:"",
      original_title:"Star Wars",
      overview:"Il y a bien longtemps, dans une galaxie très lointaine... La guerre civile fait rage entre l'Empire galactique et l'Alliance rebelle. Capturée par les troupes de choc de l'Empereur menées par le sombre et impitoyable Dark Vador, la princesse Leia Organa dissimule les plans de l’Étoile Noire, une station spatiale invulnérable, à son droïde R2-D2 avec pour mission de les remettre au Jedi Obi-Wan Kenobi. Accompagné de son fidèle compagnon, le droïde de protocole C-3PO, R2-D2 s'échoue sur la planète Tatooine et termine sa quête chez le jeune Luke Skywalker. Rêvant de devenir pilote mais confiné aux travaux de la ferme, ce dernier se lance à la recherche de ce mystérieux Obi-Wan Kenobi, devenu ermite au cœur des montagnes désertiques de Tatooine...",
      release_date:"1977-05-25"
   }
]
```

The full code of my component where I call the data list :

```
// Components/Search.js

import React from 'react'
import { StyleSheet, View, TextInput, Button, Text,FlatList } from 'react-native'
import films from '../Helpers/filmsData'


class Search extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.main_container}>
        <TextInput style={styles.textinput} placeholder='Titre du film'/>
        <Button title='Rechercher' onPress={() => {}}/>
      </View>
    )
  }

  
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.main_container}>
        <TextInput style={styles.textinput} placeholder='Titre du film'/>
        <Button title='Rechercher' onPress={() => {}}/>
        <FlatList
          data= { films } 
          keyExtractor={(item) => item.id.toString()}
          renderItem={({item}) => <Text>{item.title}</Text>}
        />
      </View>
    )
}
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  main_container: {
    flex: 1,
    marginTop: 20
  },
  textinput: {
    marginLeft: 5,
    marginRight: 5,
    height: 50,
    borderColor: '#000000',
    borderWidth: 1,
    paddingLeft: 5
  }
})

export default Search
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// this is incorrect export syntax
export default data = [
  ...
]
```

The correct export syntax is

```
export default [

]
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/export